# Optimize Big `IN` SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have a this big SQL:

```
SELECT id,kdt_id,kdt_goods_id,fx_price,min_retail_price,max_retail_price,
fx_count,stock_num,sold_num,recommend_level,is_display,is_delete,
quit_time,review_status,fx_auth,level_discount_auth,is_fx_delete,
sold_status 
FROM apple_goods 
WHERE 1 and `kdt_goods_id` in (
    '44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839',
    '44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839',
    '44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839',
    '44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839',
    '44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839','44089839',
    '96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525',
    '96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525',
    '96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525',
    '96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525',
    '96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525',
    '96611525','96611525','96611525','96611525','142061451',
    '142061451','142061451','142061451','142061451','142061451',
    '142061451','142061451','142061451','142061451','142061451',
    '142061451','142061451','142061451','142061451','142061451',
    '142061451','142061451','142061451','142801551','142801551',
    '142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551',
    '142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551',
    '142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551',
    '142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551','142801551',
    '143381529','143381529','143381529','143381529','143381529',
    '143381529','147713054','147713054','147713054','147713054',
    '147713054','147713054','147713054','148164398','148164398',
    '148164398','148164398','148164398','148164398','148164398',
    '148164398','148164398','148164398','148164398','148296160',
    '148296160','148296160','148296160','148296160','148296160',
    '151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722',
    '151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722',
    '151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722',
    '151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722','151063722',
    '151063722','153933372','153933372','153933372','153933372',
    '153933372','153933372','154447237','154447237','154447237',
    '154447237','154447237','154447237','154447237','158137781',
    '158137781','158137781','158137781','158137781','158137781',
    '158217358','158217358','158217358','158217358','158217358',
    '158217358','158217358','158217358','158217358','158217358',
    '158217358','158217358','158217358','158246547','158246547',
    '158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547',
    '158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547',
    '158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547',
    '158246547','158246547','158246547','158246547','160734561',
    '160734561','160734561','160734561','160734561','160734561',
    '162435844','162435844','162435844','162435844','162435844',
    '162435844','162435844','162435844','162435844','162435844',
    '162435844','162435844','162435844','163784258','163784258',
    '163784258','163784258','163784258','163784258','163784258',
    '163784258','163784258','163784258','163784258','163784258',
    '163784258','163784258','163784258','163784258','163784258',
    '163784258','163784258','163800813','163800813','163800813',
    '163800813','163800813','163800813','163800813','163800813',
    '163800813','163800813','163800813','163803246','163803246',
    '163803246','163803246','163803246','163803246','164617535',
    '164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535',
    '164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535',
    '164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535',
    '164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535','164617535')
```

How to optimize it ?

the `explain` :

````
```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: apple_goods
         type: range
possible_keys: kdt_goods_id
          key: kdt_goods_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 20
        Extra: Using index condition
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
````

Comment: Well, you can insert all these values into temporary table and inner join to it in your query. Also note - you have a lots of duplicate values in this list, which is not needed for filtering logic.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev does this have improvement than the original ?

Comment: Removing duplicates from list definitely will increase performance, if we're talking about it. In any case, it will be slightly more readable (from my point of view).

Comment: can we see your `explain` statement please

Comment: Remove duplicates and you will have small `IN` ;)

Comment: If you developers/schema are that bad you need to hard code Ids at least you can create a column flag, set it to the right rows and use it instead

Comment: Have all `kdt_goods_id` anything in common? If they do, it would be better to create a new column in apple_goods table (like 'apples', 'pears', etc)  and then filter by this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the duplicates from your `IN`, benchmark this against creating a temporary table maybe.

```
SELECT id,kdt_id,kdt_goods_id,fx_price,min_retail_price,max_retail_price,
fx_count,stock_num,sold_num,recommend_level,is_display,is_delete,
quit_time,review_status,fx_auth,level_discount_auth,is_fx_delete,
sold_status 
FROM apple_goods 
WHERE 1 and `kdt_goods_id` in
('96611525',
'44089839',
'164617535',
'163803246',
'163800813',
'163784258',
'162435844',
'160734561',
'158246547',
'158217358',
'158137781',
'154447237',
'153933372',
'151063722',
'148296160',
'148164398',
'147713054',
'143381529',
'142801551',
'142061451')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use table to store the values you have in your `IN` list and then join against that. If this is transient data, you could use temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (yourid VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT IGNORE INTO t1 VALUES
    ('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),
    ('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),
    ('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),
    ('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),
    ('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),
    ('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),('44089839'),
    ('44089839'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),('96611525'),
    ('96611525'),('96611525'),('142061451'),('142061451'),
    ('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),
    ('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),
    ('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),
    ('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),('142061451'),
    ('142061451'),('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),
    ('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),
    ('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),
    ('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),
    ('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),
    ('142801551'),('142801551'),('142801551'),('143381529'),
    ('143381529'),('143381529'),('143381529'),('143381529'),
    ('143381529'),('147713054'),('147713054'),('147713054'),
    ('147713054'),('147713054'),('147713054'),('147713054'),
    ('148164398'),('148164398'),('148164398'),('148164398'),
    ('148164398'),('148164398'),('148164398'),('148164398'),
    ('148164398'),('148164398'),('148164398'),('148296160'),
    ('148296160'),('148296160'),('148296160'),('148296160'),
    ('148296160'),('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),
    ('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),
    ('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),
    ('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),
    ('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),('151063722'),
    ('151063722'),('151063722'),('153933372'),('153933372'),
    ('153933372'),('153933372'),('153933372'),('153933372'),
    ('154447237'),('154447237'),('154447237'),('154447237'),
    ('154447237'),('154447237'),('154447237'),('158137781'),
    ('158137781'),('158137781'),('158137781'),('158137781'),
    ('158137781'),('158217358'),('158217358'),('158217358'),
    ('158217358'),('158217358'),('158217358'),('158217358'),
    ('158217358'),('158217358'),('158217358'),('158217358'),
    ('158217358'),('158217358'),('158246547'),('158246547'),
    ('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),
    ('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),
    ('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),
    ('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),
    ('158246547'),('158246547'),('158246547'),('160734561'),
    ('160734561'),('160734561'),('160734561'),('160734561'),
    ('160734561'),('162435844'),('162435844'),('162435844'),
    ('162435844'),('162435844'),('162435844'),('162435844'),
    ('162435844'),('162435844'),('162435844'),('162435844'),
    ('162435844'),('162435844'),('163784258'),('163784258'),
    ('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),
    ('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),
    ('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),
    ('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),('163784258'),
    ('163784258'),('163800813'),('163800813'),('163800813'),
    ('163800813'),('163800813'),('163800813'),('163800813'),
    ('163800813'),('163800813'),('163800813'),('163800813'),
    ('163803246'),('163803246'),('163803246'),('163803246'),
    ('163803246'),('163803246'),('164617535'),('164617535'),
    ('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),
    ('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),
    ('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),
    ('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535'),
    ('164617535'),('164617535'),('164617535');
```

Above statement creates the temporary table, inserts data into it and also removes all the duplicates.

Once that's done, then you just use your table in you query:

```
SELECT id,kdt_id,kdt_goods_id,fx_price,min_retail_price,max_retail_price,fx_count,stock_num,sold_num,recommend_level,is_display,is_delete,quit_time,
review_status,fx_auth,level_discount_auth,is_fx_delete,sold_status 
FROM apple_goods
JOIN t1 ON (yourid=kdt_goods_id);
```

I'd also suggest that you match types in your temporary table and columns you `JOIN` against, e.g. if `kdt_goods_id` is `INT` then `yourid` in your temporary table should be `INT`.

Comment: does this improve performance ? if I reduce the 'IN' set by application, then pass to the mysql, It's better ?

Comment: It might improve, but it isn't so clear cut. Is this the only data set you pass to `IN` or are there others? Does it ever change? Is the query built dynamically?